# Como trabalhar com Data e Hora em NodeJS, Mongoose e TypeScript

Tags: node.js, typescript, mongodb, mongoose

Bom dia pessoal,
Eu venho do mundo java e estou iniciando em NodeJS.

Estou com uma dificuldade de entender como trabalhar com datas e horas no NodeJS.

Esse é um exemplo do modelo que quero usar:

```
    export interface teste extends mongoose.Document {
        descricao: string,
        dataTeste: ????,
        horarioInicial: ????,
        horarioFinal: ????,
        dataHoraRegistro: ????
    }

    const testeSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
        descricao:{
            type: String,
            required: true,
            maxlength: 200,
            minlength: 3
        },
        dataTeste:{
            type: ?????,
            required: true
        },
        horarioInicial:{
            type: ?????,
            required: true
        },
        horarioFinal:{
            type: ?????,
            required: true
        },
        dataHoraRegistro:{
            type: ?????,
            required: true
        }
    }

export const Teste = mongoose.model<Teste>('Teste', testeSchema)
```

Em todos os locais que deixei ???? eu não sei o que colocar.

- No campo dataTeste eu preciso registar apenas datas, sem as horas.
- Nos campos horarioInicial e horarioFinal eu preciso armazenar apenas horas, sem datas.
- No campo dataHoraRegistro eu preciso armazenar o momento que aconteceu alguma coisa (data e hora).

Como vocês fazem isso?

Answer (score 1):

Uma boa forma de você conseguir isso é analisando a documentação(https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongoose e https://mongoosejs.com/docs/schematypes.html#dates), vou tentar sintetizar pra ti.

Acredito ser uma limitação do Mongoose (Não utilizo o mesmo, mas conheço bem JS e estudei um pouco sobre ele para te responder), o que você pode fazer é o seguinte:

- No campo dataTeste, você guarda o date completo, porém na hora de utilizar, só utilize a data e desconsidere as horas (cuidado com o timestamp);
- Nos campos horarioInicial e horarioFinal, faça o mesmo armazene a data e hora e somente utilize as horas, pelo que entendi o inicio e fim do seu evento se dará no mesmo dia, logo, pode ser feito assim;
- No campo dataHoraRegistro você seta também como Date e adiciona a propriedade default com o valor Date.now;

Uma boa pedida para você manipular datas no JS é o moment (https://momentjs.com/), sempre utilizo.

Espero ter ajudado.

Segue abaixo um exemplo de como ficaria seu código fonte:

```
export interface teste extends mongoose.Document {
    descricao: string,
    dataTeste: Date,
    horarioInicial: Date,
    horarioFinal: Date,
    dataHoraRegistro: Date
}

const testeSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    descricao:{
        type: String,
        required: true,
        maxlength: 200,
        minlength: 3
    },
    dataTeste:{
        type: Date,
        required: true
    },
    horarioInicial:{
        type: Date,
        required: true
    },
    horarioFinal:{
        type: Date,
        required: true
    },
    dataHoraRegistro:{
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now,
        required: true
    }
}

export const Teste = mongoose.model<Teste>('Teste', testeSchema)
```

Um conselho de Dev para Dev, no meu ponto de vista, uma das grandes dádivas do JS/TypeScript é ser uma linguagem onde você consegue fazer muito escrevendo menos, quando comparado ao JAVA por exemplo, acredito que o módulo que você escreveu poderia ser menor.

Comment: Cara, que resposta fantástica! A dica foi excelente. Eu tinha colocado a hora como string, mas depois eu não estava sabendo como fazer cálculos com as horas. Também vou tentar a redução na quantidade de código. Muito obrigado mesmo pela atenção na resposta.

Comment: Fico feliz em ter ajudado! :D